# Vertica/SQL: Getting medians per group

Tags: sql, vertica

It's straight forward to get average values per group in vertica/sql

```
select sym, AVG(qty)
from data
where 1=1
and trading_date = '2018-01-08'
group by sym;
```

This generates one row for each sym, and lists the sym and its corresponding average quantity.

However, this doesn't seem to work if we replace AVG with MEDIAN. Is there a way to get the equivalent table (one row per sym) with medians instead of averages?

In KDB, this would be trivial:

```
select med qty by sym from data where trading_date=2018.01.08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`MEDIAN`](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/SQLAnalytics/CalculatingAMedianValue.htm) window function.

```
select distinct sym, MEDIAN(qty) OVER(PARTITION BY sym) 
from data
where trading_date = '2018-01-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it distasteful, but you can do:

```
select distinct sym, AVG(qty) over (partition by sum) as avg_qty,
       median(qty) over (partition by sum) as median_qty
from data
where 1=1 and trading_date = '2018-01-08';
```

`select distinct` is used instead of `group by` when you need functionality from an analytic function that is not available as an aggregation function.